# How to consume SAMLResponse using ADFS?

Tags: saml, adfs3.0

We need to setup ADFS as a service provider. So, we tried to send saml response to ADFS. We configured stubs for claims provider, RPT and created certs. We try to send saml to adfs/ls/IdpinitiatedSignon.aspx with RelayState.

Here is Saml Response example.

```
<samlp:Response ID="_6bcc31a5-fcc2-46a6-a84d-0df2cb5bed17" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-03-27T12:37:34.839Z" Destination="https://srv2012-test-dc.testdomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx" InResponseTo="_728ac076-7b14-4ce2-8efb-ed5c8c9b85f3" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">anthem.cn.com</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_eeaaab87-0fcc-4ec1-93d3-ed623b27130c" IssueInstant="2019-03-27T12:37:41.843Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>anthem.cn.com</Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="#_eeaaab87-0fcc-4ec1-93d3-ed623b27130c">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>MkByT8QpjpBFszlr74Rx0IZNewk=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>AYhBtCEl4CrsgsuWMaLEDP...</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>MII...</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID>VALERA</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_728ac076-7b14-4ce2-8efb-ed5c8c9b85f3" NotBefore="2019-03-27T12:32:34.839Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-03-27T13:37:34.847Z"/>
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions>
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>https://beta3dev.test.com/</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-03-27T12:37:41.843Z" SessionIndex="_56b775bf-32a7-4f35-a370-d707a653a5aa">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="FirstName">
                <AttributeValue>valera</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

It seems to be valid, we checked by online validators, but ADFS throws exception:

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.UnsupportedSamlResponseException: MSIS7029: The SAML response has content that is not supported.

So, The question is: **What's wrong with saml?**

P.S. Actually, we don't know how an idp intiated scenario works. Maybe there is some minimum pack of claims or we can't login because we don't have working stubs. It will be nice to get some more info about this dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's working now.

1. There is no request in IdP initiated scenario, so we removed all InResponseTo attributes.
2. AuthnContext changed to PasswordProtectedTransport.

Name Id can be included but there should be no NotBefore attribute.